# BaseX 9.1.2 : issues with entities on xslt:transform

Tags: xslt, basex

I'm having some trouble to transform xml nodes containing entities using xslt:transform() with BaseX :

```
let $xsl := doc('xsl/commun.xsl')
return
xslt:transform(<node>ééé</node>, $xsl)
```

gives

```
[FODC0002] "" (Line 1): L'entité "eacute" était référencée, mais pas déclarée.
```

I have created my database with/without intparse and/or DTD options, with no changes ([options basex](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Options)).

xslt:processor() and xslt:version tell that I'm using java 1.0 as processor.

**Here is the declaration of my xslt:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="no" exclude-result-prefixes="#all"/>xslt:transform 
<xsl:template match="/"/>
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong... Should I declare any entity I want to use in the XSL file?

Comment: So where in your posted code do you use any "entities"? `<node>ééé</node>` doesn't have any. `<node>&eacute;</node>` would have an entity reference to an undeclared entity named `eacute`. To parse that as XML you would need to have a DTD declaring the entities as needed or parse it with BaseX's internal parser I think which has options to support refererences to known HTML entities like `eacute`.

Comment: Thanks for clarify this ! I misinterpreted what the error message said.

Comment: `xslt:transform-text()` would solve that problem, too, in case you don't need the result as nodes

Comment: see also: https://mailman.uni-konstanz.de/pipermail/basex-talk/2016-March/010393.html

Answer (score 0):

> xslt:processor() and xslt:version tell that I'm using JAVA 1.0 as processor.

As explained [here](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/XSLT_Module) "XSLT 3.0 will be enabled if Version 9.x of the Saxon XSLT Processor (saxon9he.jar, saxon9pe.jar, saxon9ee.jar) is found in the classpath"

Just has to add [saxon9he.jar](https://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/files/Saxon-HE/) in {Basex Folder}/lib/custom and that's fine

Hope that help